# Is it possible to send a value to php file whilst performing a jquery GET request

Tags: php, jquery, variables, get, request

I am making a GET request in jQuery to a PHP file and need to send a variable to the PHP for use in the query. Is this possible? I want to grab the emailAddress variable in the php.

```
 function getData(){

    var emailAddress = "myemail@gmail.com";

    $.getJSON('myfile.php', function(data){             
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    $("#userAge").val(val.age);     
                                          });
            });
 }
```

So in the PHP i want to be able to select all that have the email address that I have passed in.

I have to use jQuery and PHP as  i am developing a hybrid app in PhoneGap that cant use PHP directly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optional second argument is used for passing parameters:

```
$.getJSON('myfile.php', { email: emailAddress }, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        $("#userAge").val(val.age);
    })
});
```

In the PHP script use `$_GET['email']` to get the email address.

Comment: This worked perfectly and I now know for future use. Appreciated, thanks.